# How to disable insertion of double quotes when loading from local infile into table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, null, load-data-infile

While importing a tab-separated-values (TSV) file, I find that there are two cases where mysql injects double quotes that I would like to disable.

*Case 1*: When the field value is empty/blank (zero characters) - instead of a `NULL`, a `""` gets inserted. I prefer it be just a `NULL`.

<del>*Case 2*: When a double quote is already in the string (i.e. `2" Square`), it replaces the occurrence of the double quote with two double quotes and it also wraps the entire string in double quotes. Example: `2" Square` gets inserted as `"2"" Square"`. I want it to be just `2" Square`, just as it is in the report.tsv file.</del>

The current SQL I am using is (report-columns is a list of columns each with the definition `VARCHAR(25) DEFAULT NULL`)

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'report.tsv' 
INTO TABLE properties 
IGNORE 1 LINES (report-columns)
```

I tried adding `FIELDS ESCAPED BY ''` but this didn't change the results.

I prefer a plan to be able to just disable this from happening in the first place in the same query that loads the file, but if that is not possible a backup plan would be to execute a *cleanup* query for all report-columns to be run immediately after import to address both cases 1 <del>and 2</del> above.

Ideas on either plan?

**Update**

After further investigation into this I determined that it was not mysql's loading of the data that was causing case 2, rather it was a clean script just before the load. The answer for using SET and NULLIF in the same query with the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE statement has resolved case 1 nicely without needing a second query cleanup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a NULL to be inserted, you can use a literal `\N` in your source text file, or the word `NULL`, depending on some of your options. This is documented in the manual for LOAD DATA INFILE: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Look for the phrase "Handling of NULL values varies according to the FIELDS and LINES options in use" and read what follows (I'm not going to copy the manual into this Stack Overflow answer).

Another option is to use an expression to modify the value on import if it's an empty string:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'report.tsv' 
INTO TABLE properties 
IGNORE 1 LINES (report-columns)
SET some_col = NULLIF(some_col, '');
```

I'm not sure what to recommend for the second case, when you have double-quotes in your input text data. I tried this, and it worked fine for me. I was able to import the string `2" square`.

It could be complicated if you use LOAD DATA INFILE with the `ENCLOSED BY '"'` option. You might want to enclose fields by some different character that doesn't appear in the text.

Comment: I’m not sure I can rely on modifying the input data file but I’ll see if I can tinker with a pre-clean script. I’ll try the set and on the fly modification. How could I handle both cases like that and sensibly do replace for that second case? In your test for the double quotes already in the field, what version of mysql are you using? I’m using 5.5 and in my real data it doesn’t work as expected. Maybe there is a conf file setting difference?

Comment: I'm using 5.6.31. I don't know of any differences between 5.5 and 5.6 with respect to LOAD DATA INFILE.

Comment: Hmm. I’m not using ENCLOSED BY and there are no field enclosing quote or other character(s) in the file. Just strings separated by tabs is all.

Comment: The extra quote wrapping for case 2 turned out to be caused by a clean script, not by the LOAD DATA INFILE that was overlooked. Thanks - marking your answer correct as it resolves case 1 and I didn't know I could set values in the same query - nice.